# Got confused about the while loops and try-except relationship in the collatz sequence

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except, collatz

I am a starter in learning Python, and I am doing the practice project of the book called Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, chapter 3. That is a collatz sequence. My code is below:

```py
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return (int(number)//2)
    else:
        if number % 2 ==1:
            return(3*int(number)+1)

print('Enter number:')

try:
    number = int(input())
    while True:
        if number != 1:
            number = collatz(number)
            print(number)
        else:
            break
except ValueError:
    print('You must input an interger!')
```

This code is running well, and until the result reached 1, it stopped.like

```
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

But when I put the Try-exception block into the While loop, then everything changed. like this:

```py
while True:
    number = int(input())
    try:
        if number != 1:
            number = collatz(number)
            print(number)
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('You must input an interger!')
```

Then the program couldn't finish the while loop till the final result 1. It stopped after just one try, like

```
3
10
```

I can't figure it out. Could anybody here explain why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have `number = int(input())` inside the `while` loop. So the program is waiting for your input.

Comment: you have to wrap the `collatz(number)` inside a `while` statetement in iorder to produce the whole collatz sequence and not only the 1st result like you have in your 1st example

Comment: What you mean by wrap the collatz() function inside the while statement? I've tried several ways, but it seems that it is wrong to put the try-except into the while loops.